# Webform validation are working but they some error

Tags: forms, webforms

When I login and page redirects to home page, it shows this notice:

> Notice: Undefined index: submitted in web_alter_form_validate() at line 19

Here is my code:

```
function web_alter_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

    if($form_id) //Change webform id according to you webformid
      {
        $form['#validate'][]='web_alter_form_validate';
        return $form;
      }

}

function web_alter_form_validate($form,&$form_state){

    if($form_state['values']['submitted']['title']){

      $val_title = $form_state['values']['submitted']['title'];
      if(preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $val_title) !== 0){
        form_set_error('title', 'Special character are not allowed in form title.');
      }
    }
    // Then use regular expression to validate it.
    // In above example i have check if phonefield is empty or not.
}
```

I have set validations on webform title.

Comment: You obvously copied an example piece of code and forgot to replace $form_id with your actual form ID. Be careful when you copy-past code that isn't yours.

Comment: @Djouuuuh its from function to check evey time form id using dsm(form_id)

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
if($form_id)
```

is doing nothing. Form ID is never something that will be considered `FALSE`. [PHP Manual says](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting):

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> - the boolean FALSE itself
> - the integer 0 (zero)
> - the float 0.0 (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string "0"
> - an array with zero elements
> - an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> - the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> - SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

Form ID is a string, name of a function really, and as such can never be empty or `"0"`.

This means your function **always enters the code block** under `if`, and appends your validator to all forms. Most forms does not have *submitted* index defined, hence warning.

You probably wanted something like

```
if($form_id == 'some_form_ID_you_know_and_I_do_not')
```

and in validator something like

```
if( isset($form_state['values']['submitted']) and !empty($form_state['values']['submitted']['title']) ){
```

Comment: how i am escape from this warning @molot

Comment: @user25762 Re-write your `if` to contain actual comparison, and only attach your validator to the form you want?

Comment: yes i want  to this

Comment: @user25762 see my updated answer and try. If it works, accept it. If not, tell me why not and I'll try to update my answer.